# docker-compose restart container if service is dead

Tags: docker-compose, docker-container

Is it possible to restart container in docker-compose if service that is running inside it returns exit code different than `0`? docker-compose.yml option `restart: always` doesn't work that way. Is there any way to solve it or is this a service issue and I should look for the answer inside of the container?

I use supervisord but adding option `autorestart=true` doesn't work even if service crashes with exit code `255` - the `RUNNING_PID` file (created by system) is not being deleted.

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 16):

`restart: always` will restart the container regardless of the exit code, so even if exit code of the process running inside the container is `0`. I'm using `restart: on-failure` and it does exactly what you describe. It restarts the container on a non zero exit code of the process. After the process exits and it is not restarted you can check the exit code using `docker-compose ps`

Comment: Thanks for reply, but my case is a little different - even if service exits with code different than 0, the container doesn't show it (it's still marked as Up in docker-compose ps).